# Git-SVN Not Allowing Me to Authenticate

Tags: git, authentication, subversion

Git 1.7.9.1 on Arch Linux:

```
git svn init -s https://app.svn.beanstalk.com/repo
Initialized empty Git repository in /path/to/repo/.git/
Authentication realm: <https://app.svn.beanstalk.com/repo:443> SVN    
Password for 'localuser':
Authentication realm: <https://app.svn.beanstalk.com/repo:443> SVN
Username: remoteuser
Password for 'remoteuser':
Authentication realm: <https://app.svn.beanstalk.com/repo:443> SVN
Username:
```

No matter how many times I enter my details, it never accepts them. I have logged in successfully with the same credentials in a web browser. I have also tried this without the `-s`, and with the `--no-minimize-url` flags. What's going on?

Comment: Do you know if it's Basic, Digest, NTLM, or Negotiate authnetication?

Comment: Pretty sure it's Basic.

Comment: Did you try svn directly? Did you try accessing the server directly per http? This probably isn't related to git or even svn.

Comment: I have the same scenario using git-svn on windows in the mingw32 shell with Git 1.8.5.5.  On my Windows x64 machine I am running TortoiseSVN 1.7.5 with SVN 1.7.3 and I can connect with SVN-cached credentials through both Tortoise and SVN command line yet when I attempt to clone the same SVN url with git-svn I get the behavior described above.

Comment: Apparently this problem went away for me after I entered my domain credentials (username, then password) 3 or 4 times in a row. Now my git-svn is working against the local svn repos just fine.

Answer (score 3):

[@DavidAlpert's advice](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/32987/git-svn-not-allowing-me-to-authenticate/162504#comment179153_32987) was correct. I fixed this by simply entering my domain credentials (username, then password) 3 or 4 times in a row.

I don't know why, but it worked for me! I repeated this as an answer here since it is easy to miss in the comments.

Answer (score 0):

I've found that it's a bug in the latest version [1.9.0](https://code.google.com/p/msysgit/downloads/detail?name=Git-1.9.0-preview20140217.exe&can=2&q=full%20installer%20official%20git), in the previous one [1.8.5.2](https://code.google.com/p/msysgit/downloads/detail?name=Git-1.8.5.2-preview20131230.exe&can=2&q=full%20installer%20official%20git) I can successfully authenticate.

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar issue while using beanstalk. And the issues was really simple-

- It asks for login user account i.e. youremail@domain.com
- Then password - Your account password

Then its asks for 'UserName' which is beanstalk username and different from your login email id. So enter your username when it asks for

- Then it asks for password which is same as your account password.

Do not missed the difference between those 'user account' and 'username' things and get locked.